# Is it possible to download Ubuntu without pre-installed applications?

Tags: upgrade, software-center, libreoffice

I am asking if there is a way to install Ubuntu with just the OS (and maybe a simple browser).

The reason I am asking about this is I get frustrated with the application set included with the install cd.  I use LTS but I don't want to be stuck using the same office applications, or browser for two years.  I don't feel adventurous enough to re-install the entire OS every six months, but I would like to get updates to my applications when then are released or if not right when they are released, then in a reasonable time thereafter. When 12.04 was released you included LibreOffice which was fine but now there is a newer, more stable version of the software.  I notice that with the applications included on the CD, you lock that release of the OS to those versions of the applications.  However, with other software in the software center, you allow the user to upgrade to the newer version easily.  Doesn't it make sense to do that with all the applications?  As it is now, if I want the newer version of an office application, I have to install OpenOffice in the terminal.

Comment: also a possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/151283/25656

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  It has nothing to do with whether it comes on the cd or not; all of the software in a release of ubuntu is fixed at release time, and only critical bug fixes are updated.  There are a small handful of exceptions to that rule, including firefox, since mozilla does a good job testing their stable releases to make sure they don't break.  Beyond that to get newer releases of software you need to obtain it from unofficial sources, such as PPAs.